# Laravel - Subir imagen (funciona) falta como recuperar la imagen del storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

Tengo este codigo en un controlador para subir IMAGENES al storage de laravel, el código funciona perfectamente ya que veo el archivo subido en el directorio /storage/app/public/banners/

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class UploadImageController extends Controller
{
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $path_img = 'banners';

    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $file = $request->file('file');

    try {
        Storage::disk('public')->put($path_img . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), File::get($file));
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return response('error',400);
    }

    return response('ok',200);
}
```

}

El problema esta al recuperar el link, ya que quiero recuperar el LINK para poder mostrar la imagen, para ello he probado esto, lo cual me genera 3 links pero ninguno funciona.

```
public function getImage()
{
    $path_img = 'banners';
    $filename = 'test_imagen.png';
    $link = storage_path('public/' . $path_img . '/' . $filename);
    echo $link;


    echo asset('banners/test_imagen.png');

    $path = storage_path('app/public/banners/') . 'test_imagen.png';
    echo $path;

}
```

Comment: Creaste el lino simbólico `artisan storage:link`?  Luego podrás hacer `asset('storage/banners/test_imagen.png');` o `Storage::url('storage/banners/test_img.jpg');` . Dale una mirada a la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk .

Comment: Si ese comando ya lo hice y no funciona

Comment: almacenas la imagen con el nombre original `$file->getClientOriginalName()` no deberias poner el nombre que deseas que tenga ejemplo `put($path_img . '/test_imagen.png', File::get($file))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya usaste el comando `php artisan storage:link` para crear el enlace simbólico, verifica que SI se encuentre allí y para mostrar la imagen bastaría con utilizar:

`asset('storage/banners/test_imagen.png')`

ó (dependiendo como tengas configurado el `.htaccess`)

`asset('public/storage/banners/test_imagen.png')`

Answer (score 1):

tiene que añadir la siguiente linea en la ruta de tu proyecto `/routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('public_imagen_url/{file}', function ($file) {
    return Storage::disk('public')->response("$file");
});
```

en caso de que lo tenga en carperta puede utilizar

```
Route::get('Archivo_file/{file}/{caperta}', function ($file,$caperta) {
    if (Storage::disk('public')->exists( $file .'/'. $caperta)) {
        return Storage::disk('public')->response($file .'/'. $caperta);
    }else{
        echo false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No entendí muy bien tu codigo pero, yo tambien uso Laravel, no se si comprendas el mio, pero si tienes archivos blade y controlador en tu proyecto tal vez si, esta es mi manera de mostrar (no te muestro como guardar ya que es mas larguito y complejo) la imagen ya guardada:

Fragmento del archivo blade (que esta en resources/views/pruebas/edit.blade.php), el input donde debería mostrar la imagen guardada es asi:

```
<div class="col-md-12">                              
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="logo">Logo</label>
    </div>
    <img  width="250" height="200" id="imagenLogo" src=" {{ $urlImage['logo'] }} " alt="" />
    <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Y fragmento de como lo llamo en el Controlador:

```
public function edit(Prueba $prueba)
{
    $urlImage['logo'] = '/storage/' . $prueba->logo;

    return view('pruebas.edit', compact('prueba', 'urlImage'));
}
```

Espero te ayude en algo, disculpa si no te es claro...